# How to read csv avoid index?

Tags: python, pandas

the csv data is like this:

```
,fixed acidity,volatile acidity,citric acid,residual sugar,chlorides,free sulfur dioxide,total sulfur dioxide,density,pH,sulphates,alcohol,quality
0,7.0,0.27,0.36,20.7,0.045,45.0,170.0,1.001,3.0,0.45,8.8,6
1,6.3,0.3,0.34,1.6,0.049,14.0,132.0,0.994,3.3,0.49,9.5,6
```

and I want here is my program:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv',delimiter=',')
group = data.drop('quality',axis=1).values
print(group[0])
```

I want the result is `7.0,0.27,0.36,20.7,0.045,45.0,170.0,1.001,3.0,0.45,8.8,6`, but the it comes `0,7.0,0.27,0.36,20.7,0.045,45.0,170.0,1.001,3.0,0.45,8.8`. So how to avoid the index column?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem your data before first `,` are not converted to index, so need `index_col=[0]`. Then after call `.values` first column is omited:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv',delimiter=',', index_col=[0])
```

Or:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col=[0])
```